# Electric field and electric potential

Tags: electric-fields, potential

I have a question about electric field inside hollow spherical conductor. 
I think I understand the concept of Faraday Cage that protect the cavity to get any electric field from an external source.

But let's imagine that the conductor is the actual source of the electric field charged by $\sigma$/2 over both inner and outer surfaces since charges will repel each other at the surface right ? Why is it not possible ? Because if you put a witness charge inside, I thought it will go at the center of the sphere to be in "equilibrium". But then we have a single point where all field lines converge which i think is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

There will not be any surface charge on the inside surface!

The charges will all migrate to get as far as possible from each other.  That puts them all on the *outside* surface.